# elastalert configure slack notification

Tags: elastalert

hi trying configure slack notification in test.yaml file , getting the below error ERROR:root:Could not load rule /opt/rules/test.yaml: Error initiating alert ['slack', {'slack_webhook_url': 'https://hooks.slack.com/servichttps://hooks.slack.com/services/abcd'}]: Could not import module slack_webhook_url: need more than 1 value to unpack
alert:
"slack"
slack_webhook_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/servichttps://hooks.slack.com/services/abcd"
is this the correct way to define the slack alert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you follow the spaces correctly and you are providing all the required arguments:

```
alert:
 - "slack"
 slack:
 slack_webhook_url: "YOUR URL"
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me , can you please also help me to write a query for seraching a particular string. i am using the following , but i think it is not matching for the word and sending alerts es_host: elasticsearch.internal
es_port: 9200
name: Example rule
type: frequency
index: logstash-*
num_events: 50
timeframe:
    hours: 4
query:
    query_string:
      "message" : "HYDERABAD"
# (Required)
# The alert is use when a match is found
alert:
- "slack"
- "debug"
slack:
slack_webhook_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/abcd'.the string HYDERABAD is not present at all in log file

Comment: Probably you can ask that as a separate question, because i would really like to know more about your query.

Comment: I am trying to send the json output data to kafka consumer (using Kafka as the Data Out instead of Email / Slack)- can anyone help how does it work - whether is it possible to add kafka